# Retrieve text of the selected item from ListView instead of object

Tags: c#, uwp

I tried getting the text of the selected item from my ListView using the following code.

`myListView.SelectedItems[0].ToString();`

However, the returned value is an object of type *MyClass*. I tried delcaring the returned value to *MyClass* as below:

`MyClass item = myListView.SelectedItems[0].ToString();`

The problem is I am following an MVVM pattern and the code snippet above is found in *View* which does not have a [direct] reference to *MyClass* so casting is not possible.

Is there a way so I can get the text of the selected item instead of an object?

I am using C# for a UWP app.

Comment: You could overwrite `ToString()` in `MyClass` so it return the text.

Comment: @noobprogrammer - Sorry no, after declaring _item_ to _ListViewItem_ instead of _MyClass_ , the intellisense does not show the _Text_ option for _item_.

Comment: Hi @MongZhu, I changed the term to 'declaring'. Sorry.

Comment: @keco's answer solved the problem. Thank you so much! I've learned something new.

Comment: @keco, you could post your answer below that will convenient people who visit this thread later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested: One simple solution is to override the `ToString()` method of `MyClass`. Just let the method return the desired text.